# Call a view controller inside a shouldStartLoadWithRequest

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have two View Controllers with scenes with UIWebViews. The main one, called MainViewController, should call the second one, called ViewController, and bring up that scene when the user tapps a link with PostPicPopUp in in it.
In the MainViewController I have:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    NSURL *urL=request.URL;
    NSString *urlStr=[urL absoluteString];
    //NSLog(@"URLL %@",urlStr);

    if ([urlStr rangeOfString:@"PostPicPopUp"].location == NSNotFound) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

So I need thee code before

```
return YES
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below do call your view controller manually:

```
// Objective-C
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];    
[self controller animated:YES completion:nil];

// Using storyboard
ViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerIdentifier"];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```